# textinput() equivalent in python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I need to accept info from the user in python's turtle. however the turtle.textinput function only works in versions 3.x and upwards is there an alternative I can use in version 2.X ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `textinput` actually does:

```
import tkSimpleDialog
tkSimpleDialog.askstring('title', 'prompt')
```

It requires you to have a turtle screen open, of course.

Comment: thank you very much this worked perfectly. and after checking python.py I realised that this is the same function it calls (y)