# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'textinput'

Tags: python, attributeerror, textinput

I use Sublime Text and have a problem with that code:

```
#coding: utf-8

import turtle

turtle.circle(20)

answer = turtle.textinput("Title", "Text")
```

When i run it, i get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'textinput'
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You don't mention your Python version. Maybe this is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105816/textinput-equivalent-in-python-2-x

Comment: Always provide the full traceback when reporting errors, so we can see where it was triggered.  Please also provide the desired result of your program (i.e. what are you trying to do?)

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in Python 2.
I thought it was Python 3.

I'll try to provide the full information next time. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Python 2.

Run

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and it will probably output something like

```
2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 26 2016, 12:10:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
```

which means that you are using Python 2.

As [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh) pointed out, Python 2's turtle module does not have the command `textinput`. If you want to run that code, you need to use python 3. If you are unsure how to switch versions, leave a comment on this post saying how you installed Python, and how you run your programs, and I'll show you how to use Python 3 instead.

If you want to continue with Python 2, then instead of that command you have to run

```
import tkSimpleDialog
answer = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Text", "Text")
```

which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, i was using Python 2. Thank you for help me to realize that.
I know how to switch the version.

Answer (score 1):

`dir(turtle)` will list all the methods and attributes available in `turtle` module. 
In python 3.4, `answer = turtle.textinput("Title", "Text")` is working. You can check if you have latest python and latest module installed.